# Display varchar type as Date/DateTime type

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, spring, datetime

Ajax accepts the value returned by the controller.

[image]

`ri_startDate and ri_endDate` type is datetime in DB (MySQL).

How do I convert the above values back to Date? (in, ajax)

```
    $(function()
{
    $('#doctorSelect').change(function()
    {
        $('#selectGugan').show();

        var doctor_idx = $(this).val();
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'selectDoctor.do',
            data: {"d_idx":doctor_idx},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(sectionDate)
            {
                // How do I convert the above values back to Date?
                console.log("sectionDate : " + sectionDate.ri_startDate);
            },
            error: function(sectionDate)
            {
                console.log("data : " + sectionDate);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And I want to put this value in    . What should I do?

```
        <div class="inputdname">
            <select class="helloDoctor_2" id="doctorSelect">
                <option>Choice Doctor</option>
                <option value="" name="ri_idx" id="ri_idx"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: `var date=new Date('your response date');
date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear();` like this you can try

Comment: @KalaiselvanA I would like to change this to yyy-MM-dd format. What should I do?

Comment: date.getFullYear(‌​) +"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getDate()

Comment: @KalaiselvanA Thank you. And the last question is, what do you do to add those values into the option tag?

Comment: already you are having any data on option?

Comment: can you able post your response data I will make an answer according to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here I have taken today date by default

```
`var date=new Date();`
```

instead of above you can take your date in response data

```
`var date=new Date('your response date')`;
```

It's is not a good practice to maintain id and name on select - option tag because select tag has n-number of options. but  I answered according to your question in above comments.

```js
$(function(){

var date=new Date();// here i have taken today date by default
var new_date=date.getFullYear()+"/"+((date.getMonth()+1)<9?+"0"+(date.getMonth()+1):(date.getMonth()+1))+"/"+date.getDate();
console.log(new_date);

$("#doctorSelect option#ri_idx").html(new_date);
$("#doctorSelect option#ri_idx").val(new_date);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputdname">
            <select class="helloDoctor_2" id="doctorSelect">
                <option>Choice Doctor</option>
                <option value="" name="ri_idx" id="ri_idx"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: please chat with me 1:1 link is https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161265/room-for-seongwon-choi-and-kalaiselvan-a

Answer (score 0):

Try to use   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`yourtable.columname`), '%e %b %Y') AS 'date_formatted' to return data from your mysql query.

Comment: The operation should be success: function () {"should this be done in?"}

Comment: try to change your mysql query to return date time from datetime stamp. Its not in your function(). You should edit your 'selectDoctor.do' file

Comment: [{date_format(ri_startDate, '%Y/%c/%e')=2017/12/22, ri_idx=106, date_format(ri_endDate, '%Y/%c/%e')=2017/12/29}, {date_format(ri_startDate, '%Y/%c/%e')=2017/12/20, ri_idx=108, date_format(ri_endDate, '%Y/%c/%e')=2017/12/26}]